# Meaning of "My high kicks are not done in a line!"

Tags: meaning, jokes, slogan

> My high kicks are not done in a line!

The above sentence appeared as a legend in a T-shirt I saw once. It accompanied the caricature of a soccer player warming up, but I didn't get the pun intended. When I told a friend of mine about this, he said that the joke might have to do with a certain expression from ballet ... I hope that you can shed some light on this enquiry of mine.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, stand and unfold yourself!

Comment: Not ballet but a chorus line, like the [Rockettes](http://enoughroomvideo.blogspot.com/2010/12/rockettes-showing-leg.html).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, StoneyB. However, I'm afraid that I still don't get it. What's a "high kick" in soccer jargon? Besides, those downvotes make me think that there is an offensive connotation of the expression, but I'm failing to see what it might be...

Comment: In soccer, a "high kick" is a kick well above the ground--typically waist level or higher--which in a referee's judgement inadvertently imperils another player and therefore constitutes prohibited "dangerous play".

Comment: Joe, not all questions are downvoted, only some. And, generally speaking, the ones that are not all that great. I wouldn't downvote so easily, but I don't think it's worth being offended. If the questions are good, they'll be upvoted anyway. Good look.

Comment: @StoneyB Actually, in football ("soccer" if you must) a high kick is also one which causes the ball to go high in the air, a kick which is not necessarily dangerous at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you. I'm from hardcore SEC football country; all I know about the global game is what I heard the coaches telling my son when he was a kid.

Comment: @Carlo_R: I know that questions may or may not be upvoted... Besides, I wouldn't have raised any hell had this particular question not received any positive votes. What prompted me to enter that first comment is the fact that I don't find it that fair to downvote stuff without leaving any type of feedback for the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, "high kicks" can refer to moves performed by a dance team; for example, these dancers are doing **high kicks in a line**:

[image]

However, the wearer of the T-shirt does her "high kicks" like this:

[image]

I think the shirt is just meant to playfully say, "I'm an athlete, not a dancer!" by making veiled references to the football (soccer) field and dance floor.

I'd also guess the T-shirt was meant to be worn by a girl, since boys don't typically high kick in a line, or proudly proclaim that they feel more at home on the athletic field, as opposed to the dance floor.

Comment: "Typically", [**but**](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_pw8VOmhhoT8/TLScNvxsDiI/AAAAAAAACOw/vDbBXVRRfyc/s1600/every_little_step.jpg) ...

Comment: @StoneyB: Sure, but in that case, I'd expect one of those guys to wear a shirt that reads, "My high kicks are done in a line!"

Comment: Think they'd wear what they're wearing if they had a choice?

Comment: Nice illustrations! A picture is worth a thousand words indeed. This is the first time I've seen an illustration in ELU. =)

Comment: @DamkerngT.: You should visit more often then. You must have missed the famous [umbrella](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70897) question. We're not on the wrong side of the [tracks](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85595); pull up a [chair](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72831) and stay for awhile ;^)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks a million! Those chairs are very informative. The knob looks so cute. And, umm, well, I still can't pick the right word to describe what I feel. But it's clear that you can really wear an umbrella!  [grin]